# Grabbing Values in for loop and assigning Corresponding TextBox

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to update the values of several textboxes based on cells within a For loop.
I am not sure how to join the variable name together to make this work.

```
For i = 1 To 2
    Task & i.value = Worksheets("BoardItems").Range("D" & i + 1)
    When & i.value = Worksheets("BoardItems").Range("G" & i + 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Ideally, with each loop: Task1 is assigned D2, then Task2 is assigned D3.... so on and on.
This will also apply to several other text boxes, When1, Due1, Who1, etc.
This is why I am doing this in a For loop, so I don't have thousands of lines of code just appending values.

Edit:
It will look more like this as a final result...

```
For i = 1 To 30
    Priority & i.List = PriorityArray
    Who & i.List = WhoArry
    Task & i.value = Worksheets("BoardItems").Range("D" & i + 1)
    When & i.value = Worksheets("BoardItems").Range("G" & i + 1)
    Who & i.value = Worksheets("BoardItems").Range("F" & i + 1)
    Date & i.value = Worksheets("BoardItems").Range("C" & i + 1)
    Priority & i.value = Worksheets("BoardItems").Range("E" & i + 1)
    Comments & i.value = Worksheets("BoardItems").Range("J" & i + 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I added an answer, but on second reading your question, it's not clear and so I have deleted the answer for now. Is `Task1` a variable holding a checkbox object or is it the name property of a checkbox? How are these checkboxes set up?

Comment: is it the name property, which is why I am having a difficult time defining it properly.
The goal output would be like Taski = ^^^^
Where i is the # we are looping through, so this will update the Task"i".Value textbox

Comment: What kind of checkbox is this? Like, how did you add it? If you run (in vba) `Task1.Value = True` does it check the `Task1` checkbox?

Comment: Its a TextBox, with the name Task1. Task1.Value = True would set the value to "True".

Comment: Oh textbox. Sorry. Was thinking checkboxes. I think my answer correctly addresses your question. I will undelete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told us, but I'm guessing you're populating controls on a userform, so something like this may be what you're looking for:

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rw As Range, i As Long
    '...
    '...
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BoardItems")
    For i = 1 To 30
        Set rw = ws.Rows(i + 1)
        Me.Controls("Priority" & i).List = PriorityArray
        Me.Controls("Who" & i).List = WhoArry
        Me.Controls("Task" & i).Value = rw.Columns("D").Value
        Me.Controls("When" & i).Value = rw.Columns("G").Value
        Me.Controls("Who" & i).Value = rw.Columns("F").Value
        Me.Controls("Date" & i).Value = rw.Columns("C").Value
        Me.Controls("Priority" & i).Value = rw.Columns("E").Value
        Me.Controls("Comments" & i).Value = rw.Columns("J").Value
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically named variables or "variable variables" is a major anti-pattern that will only lead to terrible places. Instead consider creating a [`scripting.dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) and having entries where the `key` is your string `task1`, `task2` etc and your `value` is the actual checkbox object. Then you can refer to the checkbox by its dictionary key.

This will look something like:

```
Sub test()
    checkboxDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    checkboxDict.add "Task1", Task1
    checkboxDict.add "Task2", Task2
    checkboxDict.add "When1", When1
    checkboxDict.add "When2", When2
    
    For i = 1 To 2
       checkboxDict("Task" & i) = Worksheets("BoardItems").Range("D" & i + 1)
       checkboxDict("When" & i) = Worksheets("BoardItems").Range("G" & i + 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

You could build that dictionary dynamically as well:

```
Sub test()
    checkboxDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For Each tb In yourWorksheet.OLEObjects
        checkboxDict.Add tb.name, tb
    Next tb

    For i = 1 To 2
       checkboxDict("Task" & i) = Worksheets("BoardItems").Range("D" & i + 1)
       checkboxDict("When" & i) = Worksheets("BoardItems").Range("G" & i + 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this more efficient? I believe using this method then, I'd have to make a separate entry for every text box value, Task(1-30), When(1-30)... etc is this correct?
Or am I misunderstanding how this works.